# How many integers $x$ satisfy that $x*p(x) \leq n$, where $p(x)$ means the largest prime factor of $x$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

I guess that the number of integers $x$ which satisfy the condition $x*p(x) \leq n$ is $O(n^{2/3})$ or $O(n^{3/4} / \ln n$), but I cannot prove it. I just write a program to count the number. The results are listed.
Note: $p(x)$ means the largest prime factor of $x$.
n         the numbers
$10^5$    1894
$10^6$    9108
$10^7$    44948
$10^8$    228102

Comment: You might count the number of p-smooth numbers between n/q and n/p, where q is the smallest prime greater than the prime p.  Gerhard "Or Try Integrating Dickman's Function" Paseman, 2018.02.01.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick observation. Choose $\alpha$ close to 1 and consider the number for which $x\leqslant n^{\alpha}=:N$, $p(x)\leqslant n^{1-\alpha}=N^{(1-\alpha)/\alpha}$. The number of such $x$ grows as $\rho(\frac\alpha{1-\alpha})N$, where $\rho$ is [Dickman's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function). It already implies that the number of $x$ satisfying $xp(x)\leqslant n$ grows faster than $n^{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha<1$.

Comment: Indeed, choosing $\alpha$ around $1-\sqrt{(\log\log n)/\log n}$ results (I believe) in the number of such $x\le n$ being at least something like $n\cdot \exp(-c\sqrt{\log n\log\log n})$.

Comment: @GregMartin well, it depends on Dickman's asymptotics for large (not fixed, but depending on $n$) values of $\alpha/(1-\alpha)$. Certainly this is well studied.